# Why is print concatenated dataframes not working as expected? The columns appear stacked and "\" is displayed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I want to concatenate the columns of several dataframes (consisting of one column of 50 rows each). For this I created a list (pdList). I save the resulting dataframe in a .dat file

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
 
pdList = [df41,df42,df43,df44,df45,df46,df47,df48,df49,df410]
df4 = pd.concat(pdList, axis=1, ignore_index = True)
df4 = df4.set_index(0)        
with open('data.dat', mode='w') as file_object: 
    print(df4, file = file_object)
```

In my .dat file I get something like:

```
                       1            2            3            4            5  \
0                                                                              
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00   
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00   
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00   
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00   
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00   
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00   
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00   
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00   
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00   
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  1.41626E-06   
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  6.85856E-06   
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  1.08720E-06   
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  5.81401E-07  1.41427E-05   
1.08693E-06  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  8.19878E-06   
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  2.40268E-07  7.20913E-05   
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  9.07282E-06  2.48039E-07  6.50033E-05   
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  1.40499E-05  4.12278E-05  4.47197E-05   
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  1.27980E-06  5.75421E-05   
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  1.75810E-07  3.47232E-07  4.44875E-09  1.49665E-05   
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  6.08986E-07  1.22084E-06  1.50104E-05   
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  2.04202E-06  1.74179E-05   
6.51087E-07  0.00000E+00  1.86156E-08  1.11622E-06  1.57557E-06  1.89979E-05   
7.75056E-07  0.00000E+00  1.92708E-06  6.71833E-06  4.00733E-06  5.49060E-05   
1.17826E-07  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  6.62876E-07  2.44164E-06  6.13978E-05   
0.00000E+00  1.65058E-08  8.43127E-07  1.02832E-06  2.71861E-06  4.95927E-05   
2.13263E-07  8.26621E-07  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  3.70866E-06  7.93644E-05   
6.29865E-07  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  1.13955E-06  3.89958E-05   
5.55463E-07  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  1.12564E-06  5.39878E-05   
3.75294E-07  0.00000E+00  8.37768E-07  5.90318E-07  5.14905E-06  1.62248E-04   
3.28319E-07  7.28500E-07  5.53308E-07  1.52239E-06  5.18830E-06  1.44271E-04   
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  1.06686E-06  2.59029E-05  9.24006E-06  1.38380E-04   
6.36885E-07  7.71040E-07  8.12182E-07  9.30359E-07  6.30421E-06  1.83351E-04   
6.89552E-07  2.12218E-07  0.00000E+00  8.70148E-07  4.22763E-06  2.13848E-04   
1.19200E-06  9.29215E-07  1.28556E-06  4.71933E-07  3.31556E-06  6.58341E-05   
0.00000E+00  4.28937E-07  2.17879E-06  2.34133E-06  6.03355E-06  4.01643E-05   
0.00000E+00  6.83031E-07  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  2.41102E-06  1.35774E-04   
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  9.67104E-07  1.10324E-05   
0.00000E+00  1.10541E-07  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  3.78998E-06   
0.00000E+00  6.45830E-07  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  2.96207E-07  3.95381E-06   
9.48865E-08  5.50943E-07  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  5.45361E-08   
4.09089E-07  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00   
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00   
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00   
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00   
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00   
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00   
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00   
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00   
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00   
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00   

                       6            7            8            9  
0                                                                
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  
0.00000E+00  1.41626E-06  1.41626E-06  1.41626E-06  1.41626E-06  
0.00000E+00  6.85856E-06  6.85856E-06  6.85856E-06  6.85856E-06  
0.00000E+00  1.08720E-06  1.08720E-06  1.08720E-06  1.08720E-06  
0.00000E+00  1.41427E-05  1.41427E-05  1.41427E-05  1.41427E-05  
1.08693E-06  8.19878E-06  8.19878E-06  8.19878E-06  8.19878E-06  
0.00000E+00  7.20913E-05  7.20913E-05  7.20913E-05  7.20913E-05  
0.00000E+00  6.50033E-05  6.50033E-05  6.50033E-05  6.50033E-05  
0.00000E+00  4.47197E-05  4.47197E-05  4.47197E-05  4.47197E-05  
0.00000E+00  5.75421E-05  5.75421E-05  5.75421E-05  5.75421E-05  
0.00000E+00  1.49665E-05  1.49665E-05  1.49665E-05  1.49665E-05  
0.00000E+00  1.50104E-05  1.50104E-05  1.50104E-05  1.50104E-05  
0.00000E+00  1.74179E-05  1.74179E-05  1.74179E-05  1.74179E-05  
6.51087E-07  1.89979E-05  1.89979E-05  1.89979E-05  1.89979E-05  
7.75056E-07  5.49060E-05  5.49060E-05  5.49060E-05  5.49060E-05  
1.17826E-07  6.13978E-05  6.13978E-05  6.13978E-05  6.13978E-05  
0.00000E+00  4.95927E-05  4.95927E-05  4.95927E-05  4.95927E-05  
2.13263E-07  7.93644E-05  7.93644E-05  7.93644E-05  7.93644E-05  
6.29865E-07  3.89958E-05  3.89958E-05  3.89958E-05  3.89958E-05  
5.55463E-07  5.39878E-05  5.39878E-05  5.39878E-05  5.39878E-05  
3.75294E-07  1.62248E-04  1.62248E-04  1.62248E-04  1.62248E-04  
3.28319E-07  1.44271E-04  1.44271E-04  1.44271E-04  1.44271E-04  
0.00000E+00  1.38380E-04  1.38380E-04  1.38380E-04  1.38380E-04  
6.36885E-07  1.83351E-04  1.83351E-04  1.83351E-04  1.83351E-04  
6.89552E-07  2.13848E-04  2.13848E-04  2.13848E-04  2.13848E-04  
1.19200E-06  6.58341E-05  6.58341E-05  6.58341E-05  6.58341E-05  
0.00000E+00  4.01643E-05  4.01643E-05  4.01643E-05  4.01643E-05  
0.00000E+00  1.35774E-04  1.35774E-04  1.35774E-04  1.35774E-04  
0.00000E+00  1.10324E-05  1.10324E-05  1.10324E-05  1.10324E-05  
0.00000E+00  3.78998E-06  3.78998E-06  3.78998E-06  3.78998E-06  
0.00000E+00  3.95381E-06  3.95381E-06  3.95381E-06  3.95381E-06  
9.48865E-08  5.45361E-08  5.45361E-08  5.45361E-08  5.45361E-08  
4.09089E-07  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  
0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00
```

Why are column 6,7,8,9 printed below the others and not as additional columns (on the right)?

I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
len("0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00   ")
```

returns 79. There is a line break every 79 characters. If you refer to [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length), you would see that all lines are to be limited to exactly 79 characters and the backslash character is used for line continuation, so this appears to not be a coincidence. And though I am not sure exactly which part went wrong (I would guess that set_option() doesn't really do anything to the write method only the terminal), I tried this:

```
with open('data.dat', mode='w') as file_object: 
   print(df4.to_string(), file = file_object)
```

which appears to solve your problem

Comment: Thank you Toby. It did work indeed. But I'm not sure I understand why.. strings can be as long as one wants? but code is limited to 79 characters?

Comment: Totally understand your confusion. The PEP8 is like a style guide. It’s not mandatory, but a lot of things are coded based on its rules. Indeed, you could write a very long string to a file on your own without line breaks. However, in this case, since we are trying to directly write a df type, we are inevitably involving the pandas package and its code behind the scenes.

Comment: While I am not familiar with the inner workings of how pandas prepares the df to be written to the file, I am guessing that somewhere along the lines of the pandas code, it does follow PEP8. By writing `.to_string()` and asking pandas to turn the df type into a single-line string first, we are only writing a string to the file, and this effectively avoids the PEP8 part of the pandas code that would have interacted with the `.write()` method if we were to directly feed the df to `.write()`.